# Python) IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

When I ran this code, the error message says **File "C:\Users\dul\Dropbox\Article\ap_final.py", line 37, in extract_data
    date=matches[1] IndexError: list index out of range**

However, I am sure all elements in the list are within the range.

```
import os,datefinder,re
import numpy as np

os.chdir('C:\Users\dul\Dropbox\Article\parsedarticles')

def matchwho(text_to_match):
    if 'This story was generated by' in text_to_match:
        return('1')
    elif 'This story includes elements generated' in text_to_match:
        return('2')
    elif 'Elements of this story were generated' in text_to_match:
        return('2')
    elif 'Portions of this story were generated' in text_to_match:
        return('2')
    elif 'Parts of this story were generated' in text_to_match:
        return('2')
    elif 'A portion of this story was generated' in text_to_match:
        return('2')
    elif 'This sory was partially generated by' in text_to_match:
        return('2')
    elif 'This story contains elements generated by' in text_to_match:
        return('2')
    elif 'This story includes information generated by' in text_to_match:
        return('2')
    elif 'This story was originally generated by' in text_to_match:
        return('1')
    else:
        return('3')


def extract_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file1:
        text1=file1.read()
    #locate the date of the article
    matches = list(datefinder.find_dates(text1))
    if len(matches) > 0:
        date=matches[1]
        strdate = str(date)
    else:
        print 'No dates found in {}'.format(filename)
        strdate = ''



    #locate the name of the company2
    matchcomp2 = text1.split(' ', 1)[0]
    #count the number of words in the article
    matchcount = re.search(r'(.*) words', text1).group(1).strip()
    #determine the article
    matchw =str(matchwho(text1))
    #list the returns in a line
    combid = matchcomp2 + "," + strdate + "," + matchw + "," + matchcount
    #save in txt format
    with open('outfile.txt', "a+") as outfile:
        outfile.write("\n"+combid)

files = os.listdir("C:\Users\dul\Dropbox\Article\parsedarticles")
for file in files:
    if ".txt" in file:
        extract_data(file)
```

I am only seeking the date (mm-dd-yyyy and time) in text file and putting them in the list. There wouldn't be a possible way that the returned output would be out of the range.

Can please someone help?

Also, is it possible that datefinder module fails to capture the date in the file? Some outputs show **incorrect** dates.....THank you!

Comment: `len(matches)` may return a `single` element too ? So that would be `matches = ['something']`, and `matches[1]` is trying to access the `index 1`, that will surely raise that `IndexError`

Comment: `matches = list(datefinder.find_dates(text1)) date=matches[0]`

Comment: If I change matches[0], I wouldn't be able to get "TIME"... I will only get the DATE...

Comment: @Philip, Is the time appended with the date? what do you get when you do `print(matches)`?

Comment: @user5173426 Yes it is attached. It shows "11-03-2018 13:33:00" for example

Comment: @Philip You could split by spaces, I have added that in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes start at 0 in python. If length of the list is equal to 1, then the maximum accessible index is 0, not 1.

See below.

```
if len(matches) > 0:
        date=matches[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a try catch in there, I would ask to print `matches` to see what it returns, probably a single element.

```
def extract_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file1:
        text1=file1.read()
    #locate the date of the article
    matches = list(datefinder.find_dates(text1))
    try:
        if len(matches) > 0:
            date=matches[0].split(" ")[1]
            strdate = str(date)
        else:
            print('No dates found in {}'.format(filename))
            strdate = ''
    except IndexError:
        print("Error: Out of Index")
```

EDIT:

Continuing from the comments, your var `matches` has a value `"11-03-2018 13:33:00"` which can be splitted by spaces to get the `time`:

```
matches = "11-03-2018 13:33:00"

print(matches.split(" ")[1])
```

OUTPUT:

```
13:33:00
```

Comment: Running this, I get **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'**

Comment: @Philip use `date=matches[0].split(" ")[1]` instead, Added that in my answer.

Comment: I still get similar error **AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'split'**

Comment: Not possible. Try print(matches[0].split(" ")[1] and what do you get?